# what is the significance of [] in RHS in JOLT specification?

Tags: java, json, jolt

I am new to JOLT. I am creating a JOLT specification to parse a JSON from one format to another. However when i use the RHS as **`"&1.name"`** it doesn't work as expected and creates a different format. But when i use **`"[&1].name"`**, it works.

I cannot share the data due to policy constraints. Giving an example

eg.
Input JSON:

```json
[
  {
    "name": "my name1"
  },
  {
    "name": "my name2"
  }
]
```

JOLT spec (*Not working*) :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "name": "&1.name"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

JOLT spec (*working*) :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "name": "[&1].name"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Please help me understand the purpose of [] on RHS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Both two spec is valid.**

**`&1`:** get 1 level up **key**.

**`[&1]`:** get 1 level up **index**.

For example in your spec, `&1` means `0` and `1` as **key** and your output can be like this:

```json
{
  "0": {
    "name": "my name1"
  },
  "1": {
    "name": "my name2"
  }
}
```

And when you using the `[&1]` means `0` and `1` as **index** of array and your output can be like this:

```json
[
  {
    "name": "my name1"
  },
  {
    "name": "my name2"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can even rephrase by replacing the **`name`** on the right hand side by an ampersand **`&`** as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "name": "[&1].&"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

in order to replicate it

Prepending both **`[&1]`** and **`&1`** targets the same level which's going up the tree **1** level in order to reach the level of the indexes of the outermost array by traversing opening curly brace(s) (**`{`**) once. But the first one yields arraywise result instead of index numbers 0,1,2 ... those are generated by the second one.